# Loose drone propeller mount, flying off at high throttle

Tags: propellers, troubleshooting

I have seen [this](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/how-to-keep-my-prop-from-flying-off-my-motor) post here that asked the same question, however, the user forgot to use one component (collar). I have similar components and even when I mount everything correctly, the mount is loose. I bought a kit for a quadcopter and 3 of the 4 propeller mounts are loose.

Like you know how the propeller should turn when the physical motor turns. well the props also turn by themselves on the surface of the motor since it is not tight there. I have tightened the nut of the propeller (cone shape thing) with some pliers pretty tightly, and that stops the propeller nut from flying off, but it doesn't stop the entire mount from flying off.

How do I tighten this? I tried to tape the motor stick thingy that the props sit on top of but it peels off as i slide the propeller mount on it. I have also added some images if needed and in the first one, you can see the how it sort of slides vertically on that motor stick thingy. Thanks!

[image][image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The piece with the threads on it should probably fit over the motor shaft (motor stick thingy) all the way down to the motor body. When tightened down the slots in the threaded piece should close up and grip the shaft tightly.
You can put a screwdriver (or similar) through the hole in the conical top piece (the nut) and use that to tighten it down.

**Fit Check**

In the bottom picture tighten this down as much as possible without it being on the motor shaft. The diameter of the hole should be less than the diameter of the shaft. If it isn't, then these mounts will never work on your motors.

Comment: When I tighten the nut, the threaded piece does not seem to tighten on the shaft because I am able to take it right off after "tightening". The piece fits into the shaft but is just a tiny bit wider than the shaft which probably allows it to slide.

Comment: omg, my apologies, you're right! this time, i tightened the nut but WHILE it was sitting on the shaft and the threaded screw thingy did indeed tighten and now the mount is firm. i should probably get a drone prop nut screw driver though because the pliers are creating scratch marks on the nut.